# Trouble Shooting Web Fonts

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts

I am in the process of developing a site and I have a somewhat unusual problem.

I am working with fonts.com to create @font-face type to my site.

I have been testing / previewing my work within Firefox - to which everything loads fine.

Though when on a mobile device / ipad / safari / chrome, my typefaces do not load.

A preview for the site is located at:

http://www.moneyworrier.com/about/team/kearsten-james.php

I could paste the entire CSS though I don't think there is anything out of place. e.g.

```
.base-menu { line-height: 18px; font-family:'Arial W01 Light'; font-size:12px;}
```

Has anyone had the same trouble? Have I done something wrong? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: argh, I had something similar, but with chrome I think. do you have all the right formats? check safari on pc

Answer (score 1):

are you using this syntax:

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

read more here: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

Comment: It's all controlled from fonts.com end. You just include the css file. One would hope they have it all together.

Comment: why not take files to localhost? download files and include in your own .css file. it would be faster. when you download the @font-face kit you get a css file.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting enough firefox actually allows you to use Webfonts from fonts.com even if you have not specified a domain within your admin system. I just went to the 'Add and Edit Domains' and realised that indeed I had not specified a domain for the CSS to appear on. Adding the domain fixed the trouble.